# FTP Delete folder which can't be selected

Tags: ftp, php

**[SOLVED BY CONTACTING HOSTER AND THEY DELETED THE FOLDER FOR ME]**

**BUT STILL, IS THERE AN ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION?**

So, I use FTP, and was recently experimenting with escaping things, and making directories.

I tried making a directory in PHP, and named it Jiahao's Website. The PHP script then cut out the spaces and then, it escaped the single quote, which was the problem.

Now there is a directory in my folder called `Jiahao\'sWebsite`.

Since it has a back slash, when deleting this folder via net2ftp, I get this error message:

[image]

**QUESTION:** How would I delete this folder, or rename it so that I can delete it again? Should I use PHP?

Note that this has nothing to do with permissions, since it does have 0777 on all files and directories, even the ones on top of the current one.

When I try to rename the directory I get the following error:

[image]

When I try to delete the directory in FileZilla, it does not work either:
(Nor does rename, with the same error: 553)

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/pages/Jiahao\'sWebsite"...
Command:    CWD /pages
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /pages
Command:    CWD Jiahao\'sWebsite
Response:   553 Prohibited file name: Jiahao\'sWebsite
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Deleting "/pages/Jiahao\'sWebsite"
Command:    CWD /pages
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /pages
Command:    DELE Jiahao\'sWebsite
Response:   553 Prohibited file name: Jiahao\'sWebsite
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/pages"...
Status: Directory listing of "/pages" successful
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server OS through SSH or remote desktop?

Comment: @Burgi I use a free host online, and am not using a dedicated computer or server to host, so I don't know, but I highly doubt SSH is possible. Is this required?

Comment: SSH would have let you into the server OS and you could have tried deleting the folder from there. Do you get similar errors if you use another FTP client like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org)?

Comment: @Burgi See my edited post. It does not work with FileZilla either.

Comment: Very odd indeed. You may have to open a support ticket with your hosting provider in order for them to delete the folder for you. I'll keep looking in the meantime.

Comment: Who is your hosting company btw?

Comment: @Burgi It is a free host. It is called FreeWebHostingArea, and it allows PHP and MySQL, which is why I chose it for my test website production.

Comment: @Burgi Solved, by contacting hoster. They deleted it for me. But still, would there be a possible answer?